# Build Ci/CD on github error: postcss-calc:: Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text

Tags: reactjs, github, shopify, cicd, polaris

I have failed to deploy my source code to the web using GitHub's CI/CD. My product still runs well on a MacBook or Windows machine with the same versions of Node, npm, and yarn, but it encounters an error on GitHub. Here are the workflow details of my file.

```
name: Build develop
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch: null
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.12.0
      - name: cp env
        run: cp ./.env.develop ./.env
      - name: Build product
        run: |
          yarn cache clean
          yarn install
          yarn build
      - name: list folder
        run: ls -l
      - name: install ssh keys
        run: |
          install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }} > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - name: scp folder to server
        run: "scp -r ./build/* root@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/var/www/test/develop/test-fe"
```

and error:

```
Warning
(1:5113) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

Warning
(1:60257) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

static/css/main.0bc37bf3.css from Css Minimizer plugin
postcss-calc:: Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.

  Erroneous area:
1: auto + var(--pc-choice-space-0) + var(--pc-choice-space-0)
^..^ webpack://./node_modules/@shopify/polaris/build/esm/styles.css:1684:2591

static/css/main.0bc37bf3.css from Css Minimizer plugin
postcss-calc:: Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.

  Erroneous area:
1: auto + var(--pc-choice-space-0) + var(--pc-choice-space-0)
^..^ webpack://./node_modules/@shopify/polaris/build/esm/styles.css:1684:2765


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have tested it on both MacBook and Windows, and it was successful. I hope to be able to run it on GitHub CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this same error in our actions when bumping polaris to 11.12. Looks like this was introduced in [11.5](https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/releases/tag/%40shopify%2Fpolaris%4011.5.0) - downgrading to 11.4 sorted it for me.

Comment: Opened an issue in github https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/issues/10223